# Getting Query of a Model You are Going to Save Magento

Tags: magento

This question pertains to Models that use an EAV resource Model or a regular model. I am wondering how to get the select of a `save()` method or a `load()` method.

Example would be something like

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(5);
```

I haven't spent time debugging, was just wondering if someone knew off hand. I don't think Magento Models use `Zend_Db` as the collections do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Magento Models do use the `Zend_Db` internally, as Magento runs on top of the famous Zend Framework..

As for your requirement, to get the SQL of a Model, that use an EAV Resource Model, is:-

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->load(5)
        ->getSelect();

// For printing the whole SQL with the Collection
var_dump($product->printLogQuery(true));

// For printing only the SQL
var_dump($product->__toString());
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I guess it doesnt work for custom models... I got fatal error. Call to a member function printLogQuery() on a non-object. I guess getSelect() returns string and is used after getCollection() method.